# Opencv Charuco Calibration board

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, aruco

I have an issue with the Charuco calibration. I have a large pre-printed board lying around that i would like to use, but my calibration results are useless. When generating my own board, I found out that it is using the correct markers but that the checkerboard is inverted, leading to different positions on the board. I use the opencv example (`create_board_charuco.cpp`) with the following parameters: `./create_board -d=0 -ml=120 -sl=150 -w=9 -h=4 -bb=1 -si=1 out_board.jpg`
I assume this difference is also why my calibration results are bad. The resulting calibration patterns are below:

What the board i have looks like:
https://calib.io/pages/camera-calibration-pattern-generator

[image]

What the layout i generated with opencv looks like

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a chance made in v4.6.0 of OpenCV. A legacy flag (default on) was already added and should be present in the next minor release.

https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/issues/3291

Comment: thank you, now I went back to opencv 4.5.0, now it generates the correct board